# NSUserDefaults with big array

Tags: objective-c, macos, core-data, nsuserdefaults

I'm building a macOS application.

I'm currently using `NSUserDefaults` to save `NSMutableArray` data with this method:

```
-(void)addPhotoUrl:(NSString*)url {
    [self.photosArray addObject:url];

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:self.photosArray forKey:@"kPhotos"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}
```

And every time the application start I run this code to load the `NSMutableArray`:

```
-(void)loadPhotosLike {
    NSArray *myRepository = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] arrayForKey:@"kPhotos"];
    if(myRepository && [myRepository count] != 0) {
        [self.photosArray addObjectsFromArray:myRepository];
    }
}
```

Until now it's work perfectly, But since the array becomes really big(64,000 items), I start to think this solution was not good enough.

There is the issue that the Array exists both in the local `NSMutableArray` and saved to the `NSUserDefaults` every time I add a new item to it, this is a good solution and not impact the local memory/app memory/writing problem to the disk?

Should I start using Core Data instead?

One of the main purposes of the array is to search for objects. Will this be faster with CoreData?

Comment: why don't you consider the save a `plist` into the `Documents/` folder? no need for core-data nor user-defaults at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per my exprience `NSUserDefaults` only use for light weight data like some preferences related data you can store in userDefaults.

Also if you store heavy/large data it will slower your app as it will store in single plist file.

And due to heavy data load on app it will create memory issue and as you are working on `MacOS` you will find memory issue rarely but in term of iOS it will definitely create problem.

I found very good blog of **Jeffrey fulton** where he define in detail where we needs to use UserDefaults or where not.

Link : [UserDefaults Limitations and Alternatives](https://jeffreyfulton.ca/blog/2018/02/userdefaults-limitations-and-alternatives)

Also adding to above UserDefault is not safe storage as data can be easily retrievable.

In your case you can use Core Data or SQLIte both are very powerful and easy to use framework for storing data.

Hope this will helps.

Comment: @CodeChanged Thanks! One of the main purposes of the array is to search for objects. is this will be faster with CodeData?

Comment: Yes much faster and easy to fetch data and filter based on your requirements.

Comment: It might be faster.  It might not.   You need to model the data correctly.   With that said, CoreData is probably a fantastic solution in that it is very well supported, quite flexible, and can grow with your storage needs quite readily.

Comment: @MTA if above answer helped and solved your problem please accept it so other can find it helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you store the image data instead of file path. Even using a database to store the image collection is not a good implementation. The big data block of image will cause database to work slow. The common implementation is to store the image data to file system first and then save the corresponding file path to the image index storage. In this case, whether using the UserDefaults or CoreData for persistent storage will be less influential.